# Division by zero error with FPDF + WriteHTML add-on

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am trying to use FPDF to generate at PDF file, this is my first time attempting it.

I have the latest FPDF files and have also set up the WriteHTML add-on. The below code is working up until the WriteHTML part at the very bottom. I am getting the error "Warning: Division by zero in /home4/fwall/public_html/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 796". When I look at line 796 of the FPDF.php, I find this:

```
// Output text in flowing mode
    $cw = &$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    $w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize; // <--LINE 796
    $s = str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb = strlen($s);
    $sep = -1;
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $l = 0;
    $nl = 1;
```

If I add a conditional statement, along the lines of:

```
if ($this->FontSize != 0) {
$wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize; // <--LINE 796
}
```

I can get the error to go away, but I know that can't be correct. Does anyone see an error in my code that would cause this?

```
require ('/home4/fwall/public_html/fpdf/fpdf.php'); 

//create a FPDF object
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdfhtml=new PDF_HTML();

//set document properties
$pdf->SetAuthor('Author Name');
$pdf->SetTitle('PRESS RELEASE - NAME OF SHOW');

//set font for the entire document
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',10);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);

//set up a page
$pdf->AddPage('P');
$pdf->SetDisplayMode(real,'default');

//display the top block
$contact = 'Contact Name';
$addline1 = '4002 2nd Ave NE, #2';
$addline2 = 'Address Line 2';
$cityzip = 'Seattle, WA 98105';
$pdf->Cell(0, 4, 'PRESS RELEASE', 0, 0, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(0, 4, 'FOR IMMEDIATE RELEASE', 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(0, 4, 'CONTACT: '.$contact, 0, 0, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(0, 4, 'KILL DATE: August 1, 2014', 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(0, 4, $addline1, 0, 1, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(0, 4, $addline2, 0, 1, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(0, 4, $cityzip, 0, 1, 'L');


//display the title
$pdf->SetFontSize(20);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'PRESS RELEASE TITLE',0,1,'C',0);

//display the sub-title
$pdf->SetFontSize(16);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'The Subtitle',0,1,'C',0);

//display the italic summary
$pdf->SetXY(10,55);
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','I',10);
$summary = 'SEATTLE - Theatre Off Jackson presents SPF 8, the annual exhibition of solo performance. Featuring four featured performers and one shorts night, the festival will occur between February 6th and March 1st, 2014. This year\'s festival is an exciting mix of experienced artists and new-comers with exciting stories to tell. From tales of a ten-day vows of silence to what it\'s like growing up with deaf parents and siblings, this year\'s festival is a potpourri of styles and stories.';
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 4, $summary , 0, 'J');

//display the main content
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);
$maincontent = '
    First line.
    Second Line?
    <ul>
        <li>
        Item 1
        </li>
    </ul>
    ';
$pdfhtml->WriteHTML($maincontent);


//Output the document
$pdf->Output('example1.pdf','I');
```

Comment: Find out why `$this->FontSize` is set to zero and fix it? BTW, your `if` statement mentions `$thisFontSize` which I'm pretty sure is a separate variable to `$this->FontSize`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo in the questions, it's correct in my code. I'll fix it above. And yeah, I've been trying to figure out why it's set to 0 with no luck. I'm hoping someone with more experience with FPDF might be able to enlighten me.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the WriteHTML add on you are using?

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php

Comment: You can use [comment replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to direct a comment at user. This way the user will be notified about your comment.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it notified upon response without mention as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WriteHTML add-on](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php) is a class called `PDF_HTML` which extends the original `FPDF`. To use the add-on functionality you have to instantiate the subclass and use it:

```
$pdfhtml=new PDF_HTML();
```

You don't need the additional instance (`$pdf`) of the parent class. Remove it and change all references of `$pdf` to `$pdfhtml` and you are good to go:

```
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', '../Classes/FPDF/font/');
require ('../Classes/FPDF/fpdf.php');
require ('writeHtml.php');


//create a PDF_HTML object
$pdfhtml=new PDF_HTML();

//set document properties
$pdfhtml->SetAuthor('Author Name');
$pdfhtml->SetTitle('PRESS RELEASE - NAME OF SHOW');

//set font for the entire document
$pdfhtml->SetFont('Helvetica','B',10);
$pdfhtml->SetTextColor(0,0,0);

//set up a page
$pdfhtml->AddPage('P');
// $pdfhtml->SetDisplayMode(real,'default'); //<-- commented this line, what is real?

//display the top block
$contact = 'Contact Name';
$addline1 = '4002 2nd Ave NE, #2';
$addline2 = 'Address Line 2';
$cityzip = 'Seattle, WA 98105';
$pdfhtml->Cell(0, 4, 'PRESS RELEASE', 0, 0, 'L');
$pdfhtml->Cell(0, 4, 'FOR IMMEDIATE RELEASE', 0, 1, 'R');
$pdfhtml->Cell(0, 4, 'CONTACT: '.$contact, 0, 0, 'L');
$pdfhtml->Cell(0, 4, 'KILL DATE: August 1, 2014', 0, 1, 'R');
$pdfhtml->Cell(0, 4, $addline1, 0, 1, 'L');
$pdfhtml->Cell(0, 4, $addline2, 0, 1, 'L');
$pdfhtml->Cell(0, 4, $cityzip, 0, 1, 'L');


//display the title
$pdfhtml->SetFontSize(20);
$pdfhtml->Cell(0,10,'PRESS RELEASE TITLE',0,1,'C',0);

//display the sub-title
$pdfhtml->SetFontSize(16);
$pdfhtml->Cell(0,10,'The Subtitle',0,1,'C',0);

//display the italic summary
$pdfhtml->SetXY(10,55);
$pdfhtml->SetFont('Helvetica','I',10);
$summary = 'SEATTLE - Theatre Off Jackson presents SPF 8, the annual exhibition of solo    performance. Featuring four featured performers and one shorts night, the festival will occur between February 6th and March 1st, 2014. This year\'s festival is an exciting mix of experienced artists and new-comers with exciting stories to tell. From tales of a ten-day vows of silence to what it\'s like growing up with deaf parents and siblings, this year\'s festival is a potpourri of styles and stories.';
$pdfhtml->MultiCell(0, 4, $summary , 0, 'J');

//display the main content
$pdfhtml->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);

$maincontent = '
    First line.
    Second Line?
    <ul>
        <li>
        Item 1
        </li>
    </ul>
    ';
$pdfhtml->WriteHTML($maincontent);


//Output the document
$pdfhtml->Output('example1.pdf','I');
```

Note that I changed the include paths on top. I also commented the line where you call `SetDisplayMode`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. FPDF is still a little bit of a mystery to me, but your answer has given me some insight (plus, it works!). I did notice though that the rendered html is not displaying with any styles or formatting, so I'll look into how to make that work better, but this at least got me over the functionality issue.

Comment: Oh, and also, the SetDisplayMode being set to real means the default view of the PDF will be at 100% of the actual dimensions of the document, as far as I can tell. It works fine without it though it seems.

Comment: Ok, then you are missing the quotes around the string *real*.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some elemets such as  got unbalanced in your pdf html. Some elements might not have been closed or started. 
It cost me 2 days to find this issue.