# Error Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\Compleanni_Label\class\fpdf.php:702 with FPDF

Tags: php, label, fpdf

i am using FPDF (version 1.83 April 2021) for create the labels in one pdf file.
This is the error:
Connessione avvenuta!
Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\Compleanni_Label\class\fpdf.php:702 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Compleanni_Label\class\PDF_Label.php(129): FPDF->MultiCell(-3, 10, 'ADRIANA ...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Compleanni_Label\index.php(27): PDF_Label->Add_PDF_Label('ADRIANA ...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Compleanni_Label\class\fpdf.php on line 702

I have three file linked together:
*PDF_Label*

```
require_once('fpdf.php');

class PDF_Label extends FPDF
{
    // Private properties
    var $_Avery_Name    = '';               // Name of format
    var $_Margin_Left   = 0;                // Left margin of labels
    var $_Margin_Top    = 0;                // Top margin of labels
    var $_X_Space       = 0;                // Horizontal space between 2 labels
    var $_Y_Space       = 0;                // Vertical space between 2 labels
    var $_X_Number      = 0;                // Number of labels horizontally
    var $_Y_Number      = 0;                // Number of labels vertically
    var $_Width         = 0;                // Width of label
    var $_Height        = 0;                // Height of label
    var $_Char_Size     = 10;               // Character size
    var $_Line_Height   = 10;               // Default line height
    var $_Metric        = 'mm';             // Type of metric for labels.. Will help to calculate good values
    var $_Metric_Doc    = 'mm';             // Type of metric for the document
    var $_Font_Name     = 'Arial';          // Name of the font

    var $_COUNTX = 1;
    var $_COUNTY = 1;


    // Listing of labels size
    var $_Avery_Labels = array (
        '5160'=>array('name'=>'5160',   'paper-size'=>'letter', 'metric'=>'mm', 'marginLeft'=>1.762,    'marginTop'=>10.7,      'NX'=>3,    'NY'=>10,   'SpaceX'=>3.175,    'SpaceY'=>0,    'width'=>66.675,    'height'=>25.4,     'font-size'=>8),
        '5161'=>array('name'=>'5161',   'paper-size'=>'letter', 'metric'=>'mm', 'marginLeft'=>0.967,    'marginTop'=>10.7,      'NX'=>2,    'NY'=>10,   'SpaceX'=>3.967,    'SpaceY'=>0,    'width'=>101.6,     'height'=>25.4,     'font-size'=>8),
        '5162'=>array('name'=>'5162',   'paper-size'=>'letter', 'metric'=>'mm', 'marginLeft'=>0.97,     'marginTop'=>20.224,    'NX'=>2,    'NY'=>7,    'SpaceX'=>4.762,    'SpaceY'=>0,    'width'=>100.807,   'height'=>35.72,    'font-size'=>8),
        '5163'=>array('name'=>'5163',   'paper-size'=>'letter', 'metric'=>'mm', 'marginLeft'=>1.762,    'marginTop'=>10.7,      'NX'=>2,    'NY'=>5,    'SpaceX'=>3.175,    'SpaceY'=>0,    'width'=>101.6,     'height'=>50.8,     'font-size'=>8),
        '5164'=>array('name'=>'5164',   'paper-size'=>'letter', 'metric'=>'in', 'marginLeft'=>0.148,    'marginTop'=>0.5,       'NX'=>2,    'NY'=>3,    'SpaceX'=>0.2031,   'SpaceY'=>0,    'width'=>4.0,       'height'=>3.33,     'font-size'=>12),
        '8600'=>array('name'=>'8600',   'paper-size'=>'letter', 'metric'=>'mm', 'marginLeft'=>7.1,      'marginTop'=>19,        'NX'=>3,    'NY'=>10,   'SpaceX'=>9.5,      'SpaceY'=>3.1,  'width'=>66.6,      'height'=>25.4,     'font-size'=>8),
        'L7163'=>array('name'=>'L7163', 'paper-size'=>'A4',     'metric'=>'mm', 'marginLeft'=>5,        'marginTop'=>15,        'NX'=>2,    'NY'=>7,    'SpaceX'=>25,       'SpaceY'=>0,    'width'=>99.1,      'height'=>38.1,     'font-size'=>9),
    );

    // convert units (in to mm, mm to in)
    // $src and $dest must be 'in' or 'mm'
    function _Convert_Metric ($value, $src, $dest) {
        if ($src != $dest) {
            $tab['in'] = 39.37008;
            $tab['mm'] = 1000;
            return $value * $tab[$dest] / $tab[$src];
        } else {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    // Give the height for a char size given.
    function _Get_Height_Chars($pt) {
        // Array matching character sizes and line heights
        $_Table_Hauteur_Chars = array(6=>2, 7=>2.5, 8=>3, 9=>4, 10=>5, 11=>6, 12=>7, 13=>8, 14=>9, 15=>10);
        if (in_array($pt, array_keys($_Table_Hauteur_Chars))) {
            return $_Table_Hauteur_Chars[$pt];
        } else {
            return 100; // There is a prob..
        }
    }

    function _Set_Format($format) {
        $this->_Metric      = $format['metric'];
        $this->_Avery_Name  = $format['name'];
        $this->_Margin_Left = $this->_Convert_Metric ($format['marginLeft'], $this->_Metric, $this->_Metric_Doc);
        $this->_Margin_Top  = $this->_Convert_Metric ($format['marginTop'], $this->_Metric, $this->_Metric_Doc);
        $this->_X_Space     = $this->_Convert_Metric ($format['SpaceX'], $this->_Metric, $this->_Metric_Doc);
        $this->_Y_Space     = $this->_Convert_Metric ($format['SpaceY'], $this->_Metric, $this->_Metric_Doc);
        $this->_X_Number    = $format['NX'];
        $this->_Y_Number    = $format['NY'];
        $this->_Width       = $this->_Convert_Metric ($format['width'], $this->_Metric, $this->_Metric_Doc);
        $this->_Height      = $this->_Convert_Metric ($format['height'], $this->_Metric, $this->_Metric_Doc);
        $this->Set_Font_Size($format['font-size']);
    }

    // Constructor
    function PDF_Label ($format, $unit='mm', $posX=1, $posY=1) {
        if (is_array($format)) {
            // Custom format
            $Tformat = $format;
        } else {
            // Avery format
            $Tformat = $this->_Avery_Labels[$format];
        }

        parent::FPDF('P', $Tformat['metric'], $Tformat['paper-size']);
        $this->_Set_Format($Tformat);
        $this->Set_Font_Name('Arial');
        $this->SetMargins(0,0);
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

        $this->_Metric_Doc = $unit;
        // Start at the given label position
        if ($posX > 1) $posX--; else $posX=0;
        if ($posY > 1) $posY--; else $posY=0;
        if ($posX >=  $this->_X_Number) $posX =  $this->_X_Number-1;
        if ($posY >=  $this->_Y_Number) $posY =  $this->_Y_Number-1;
        $this->_COUNTX = $posX;
        $this->_COUNTY = $posY;
    }

    // Sets the character size
    // This changes the line height too
    function Set_Font_Size($pt) {
        if ($pt > 3) {
            $this->_Char_Size = $pt;
            $this->_Line_Height = $this->_Get_Height_Chars($pt);
            $this->SetFontSize($this->_Char_Size);
        }
    }

    // Method to change font name
    function Set_Font_Name($fontname) {
        if ($fontname != '') {
            $this->_Font_Name = $fontname;
            $this->SetFont($this->_Font_Name);
        }
    }

    // Print a label
    function Add_PDF_Label($texte) {
        // We are in a new page, then we must add a page
        if (($this->_COUNTX ==0) and ($this->_COUNTY==0)) {
            $this->AddPage();
        }

        $_PosX = $this->_Margin_Left+($this->_COUNTX*($this->_Width+$this->_X_Space));
        $_PosY = $this->_Margin_Top+($this->_COUNTY*($this->_Height+$this->_Y_Space));
        $this->SetXY($_PosX+3, $_PosY+3);
        $this->MultiCell($this->_Width, $this->_Line_Height, $texte);
        $this->_COUNTY++;

        if ($this->_COUNTY == $this->_Y_Number) {
            // End of column reached, we start a new one
            $this->_COUNTX++;
            $this->_COUNTY=0;
        }

        if ($this->_COUNTX == $this->_X_Number) {
            // Page full, we start a new one
            $this->_COUNTX=0;
            $this->_COUNTY=0;
        }
    }
```

PdfLabel have only setting for label format, and a file to invoke:

```
<?php
    
    require 'class\PdfLabel.php';
    require 'connessione_server.php';
    $pdf = new PdfLabel(PdfLabel::$labelFormats['101700']);
        
        $pdf->Open();
    
         
         
    
     $query= "SELECT distinct NOME ,COGNOME ,INDIRIZZO ,CAP,CITTA FROM COMPLEANNI_PROVA where nome='adriana' and mesenasc='07' and DIPENDENTE!='Y' and dospro='Gestioni' and filiale='0'";
     $query_conn=sqlsrv_query($con,$query);
        //$row= sqlsrv_rows_affected($query_conn); 
        //$rows=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_conn);
        
        
    
    
        while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_conn))
    {
        // testo dell'etichetta
        $text = $row['NOME']." ".$row['COGNOME']."\n";
        $text.= $row['INDIRIZZO']."\n";
        $text.= $row['CITTA']."\n";
        $text.= $row['CAP']."\n";
        $pdf->Add_PDF_Label($text);
    }
    
        $pdf->Output('D','labels.pdf');
    ?>
```

I can not understand where I am wrong can you help me? FPDF file is on the official website, I have not changed anything. The error says it is in line 702

Comment: Where do you call `AddPage()`?

Comment: @Claudia Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668677/division-by-zero-error-with-fpdf-writehtml-add-on